# successCallback with timeToken not being called

Tags: java, pubnub

I wrote a simple program below to recieve messages using pubnub in Java. The problem I am facing is I am unable to retrieve `timetoken` of the received message. This callback is never called although it exists in the API

```
 @Override
                public void successCallback(String channel, Object message, String timeToken){
                   System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : " + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
                   System.out.println(timeToken);
                }
```

The callback without `timetoken` is called though. Can anyone tell me how can I retrieve the timetoken of the message.

```
import java.io.IOException;

    import com.pubnub.api.*;

import org.json.*;

public class Main{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Pubnub pubnub =
         new Pubnub("demo", "demo");

      pubnub.setUUID("1");

      try{
         pubnub.subscribe("test", new Callback(){

            @Override
            public void connectCallback(String channel, Object message){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : CONNECT on channel:" + channel + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                  + message.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void disconnectCallback(String channel, Object message){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : DISCONNECT on channel:" + channel + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                  + message.toString());
            }

            public void reconnectCallback(String channel, Object message){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : RECONNECT on channel:" + channel + " : " + message.getClass() + " : "
                  + message.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : " + message);
            }


            @Override
            public void successCallback(String channel, Object message, String timeToken){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : " + channel + " : " + message.getClass() + " : " + message.toString());
               System.out.println(timeToken);
            }

            @Override
            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error){
               System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE : ERROR on channel " + channel + " : " + error.toString());
            }

         });

         pubnub.history("akosha1", 100, new Callback(){

            public void successCallback(String channel, Object response){
               System.out.println(response.toString());
            }

            public void errorCallback(String channel, PubnubError error){
               System.out.println(error.toString());
            }

         });

         try{
            System.in.read();
         } catch (IOException e){
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

      } catch (PubnubException e){
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: The TimeToken on Subscribe is not reliable as an identifier because it is a moving target and will change based on client connections.  What are you using the TimeToken for in your code?  There are some best practice options available depending on your use case ;-)

Comment: Please contact us at support@pubnub.com so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish, and can guide you to success (either via a fix on the client, existing functionality, or a workaround).

Comment: This successcallback used to be called with all subscribe calls, if I recall. I upgraded to 3.7.0 and it no longer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the timetoken easily by building the java sdk jar yourself and altering the file PubnubCore.java and altering the line number 2617 to this :

```
if (!isWorkerDead(hreq)) 
                callback.successWrapperCallback(channel, PubnubUtil.parseJSON(message), timeToken);
```

and build the pubnub jar again.

and then you can call

```
@Override
    public void successCallback(String channel, Object message, String timetoken) {
        System.out.println("PUBNUB:"+channel + " : "
        + message.getClass() + " : " + timetoken+" : "+message.toString());
    }
```

I can share the updated jar if you want to skip this process.

Answer (score 3):

This API has been added in the latest PubNub Java SDK, v3.7.2 (or later).
https://github.com/pubnub/java/tree/master/java